# What is the pattern used by Google Tag Manager in order to observe de `dataLayer` Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, observer-pattern, key-value-observing, google-tag-manager

I observed the `dataLayer` array and I don't see any changes to `push`. No custom methods at all, actually. How is GTM observing the changes to the array? As far as I know, changes to an `Array` don't throw any events, do they?

---

### Edit:

I did some more research and found Google's library for interacting with the `dataLayer`: https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper#listening-for-messages
I'll take a look at the code and maybe even answer my own question if I understand the inner workings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern used by GTM is **publish** / **subscriber**

Some details in code that helps to recognize it: line 76 and 181 of the https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper/blob/master/src/helper/helper.js

And finally line 114 and 119

```
// Add listener for future state changes.
  var oldPush = dataLayer.push;
  var that = this;
  dataLayer.push = function() {
    var states = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    var result = oldPush.apply(dataLayer, states);
    that.processStates_(states);
    return result;
  };
```

Take a look into `states` variable and how it is passed to `this.processStates_()`

Comment: Hi @Krzysztof. Is this library for dataLayer interaction part of the default GTM library itself ? I suppose the "processStates" function is the final handler for the data-to-be-sent requests ...? Thx.

Comment: @Rik Yes - it is a part of GTM library. Second question – depends how you define "final" as `helper.DataLayerHelper.prototype.processStates_` calls all listeners each time the model is updated. Any listener that watches for changes will be informed that change occurs.

Comment: ..and (I carry on by myself) only if a tag firing rule is associated with that change, a request is made and data are sent..is this? My scenario consists in an ecommerce purchase event by a page-load dataLayer.push. This is a change, but no related request is done. Could the reason be that no event-firing rule (which should match "purchase") is associated with my Analytics tag ?? Thanks so much